# Java Spring Boot разработка объектной модели JSON

Tags: java, json, spring, rethinkdb

Мое приложение на Spring Boot принимает JSON с 4-кратной вложенностью. В базе RethinkDB надо сохранить самую вложенную часть и несколко полей из внешней части. Каким способом лучше распарсить этот JSON?

- создать объектную структуру, полностью повторяющую структуру JSON
- или распарсить вложенную часть при помощи `@JsonProperty` и процедуры распаковки?

Сохраненные документы также надо будет извлекать из БД как объекты.

Как лучше поступить?

Answer (score 1):

Объектной структурой. С ними работать проще